# Static Website Definition With Restful Dynamic Content

Tags: angular, rest, amazon-s3

I am in the process of creating a Dashboard app for monitoring of backend services in Angular technology. The app would interact continuously with backend (make API calls) to get the current status of services.

My question is, does this kind of scenario qualify for the app to be hosted in AWS S3 as a static application since the HTML is all static but only content changes continuously?

Comment: Yes, S3 can totally handle this type of SPA.

Comment: I read some articles and they claim that static website is something that is pre-loaded with data. Is this a misconception? If I have to make POST calls, can S3 handle that scenario as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 can handle this scenario. I was able to develop and deploy this Single Page Application with the requirements on Amazon S3.